# Why i can't build yocto image? Bitbake error [errno2]

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake

i try to build rpi image, but get this mistake.

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 179, in wrapped
    return func(fn, *args)
  File "/home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 203, in parse_config_file
    return bb.parse.handle(fn, data, include)
  File "/home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 113, in handle
    return h['handle'](fn, data, include)
  File "/home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 124, in handle
    abs_fn = resolve_file(fn, data)
  File "/home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 131, in resolve_file
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, "file %s not found in %s" % (fn, bbpath))
IOError: [Errno 2] file  /conf/layer.conf not found in /home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/rpi-build

ERROR: Unable to parse  /conf/layer.conf: [Errno 2] file  /conf/layer.conf not found in /home/ubuntu14/raspberryPi3/rpi-build
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TObJF.png)

Comment: Can you snippet code between125-131?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got previously the same error, now I found a solution

Pay attention into
"root/rpi-build/conf/bblayers.conf".

You have to indent the line

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-raspberrypi \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  "
```

With double space of linux character

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, I found a solution.
When you are config "bblayers.conf" file.You must type path of class accurate.
e.g:  ../meta-arm -> wrong and get mistake "ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last): ......"
../meta-arm/meta-arm -> true
because  meta-arm layer consist of meta-arm, meta-arm-bsp ,...